# JavaScript: Modal form fadeInDown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created one Modal form purely `Javascript` and `Css`. I really like [Bootstrap's](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) modal animation where the card appeared `FadeInDown` and for closing `FadeInUp`. I want to implement that animation on my app. I have created one animation called `FadeIn` but I don't how to implement that logic in `Javascript.` I have shared my code in the code snippet. I will be glad if someone shows me how to implement the animation in javascript.

```js
const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
const btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
const span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function () {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function () {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (event.target === modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
})
```

```css
  .modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  }


  /* Modal Content */
  .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(60,75,100,.14);
  }

  .close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }



/* animation*/
.fade{
  animation: fadeIn .1s ease-in .5s both;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
      opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
      opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
  <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <form action="submit">
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
          <label for="email">email:</label>
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
          <label for="Telephone">Telephone</label>
          <input type="number" id="telephone" name="telephone"><br><br>
          <label for="description">Description:</label>
          <input type="text" id="description" name="description"><br><br>
          <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: https://animate.style/ u can use this

Comment: I don't want to use any Library .

Comment: @krisna check my answer as well. it just fades in and out the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding a new class called `.visible` and use transition for your transform and opacity :)

```js
const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
  const btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  const span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.classList.add("visible");
  };

  span.onclick = function () {
    modal.classList.remove("visible");
  };

  document.body.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
      modal.classList.remove("visible");
    }
  });
```

```css
        .modal {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }

  /* Modal Content */
  .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(60, 75, 100, 0.14);
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    transition: 0.75s ease;
    transition-property: opacity, transform;
  }

  .close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .visible {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }

  .visible > .modal-content {
    transform: translateY(0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
  <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <form action="submit">
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
          <label for="email">email:</label>
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
          <label for="Telephone">Telephone</label>
          <input type="number" id="telephone" name="telephone"><br><br>
          <label for="description">Description:</label>
          <input type="text" id="description" name="description"><br><br>
          <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Another suggestion here is to set `aria-hidden` to true when the modal is closed and false if it's open. This will prevent the voice-over from reading the markup while the modal is closed

Comment: Thanks man! Just one thing, I want only the card `fadeInDown` not the background-color.

Comment: oh, give me a sec.

Comment: Thanks man! I think now I know where to play the css :D. wish you all the best. 

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

To do this we can move `.modal-content`'s `-40px` to up initially,and when modal opened , after a delay move it to its default place.
Can apply this animation to closing modal aswell.

1. Add `opacity:0;` and `transform:translateY(-40px);` to `.modal-content` in css
2. Add new rule :

   ```
   .modal-content.active{`
        opacity: 1;
        transform:translateY(0);
   }
   ```
3. define `modal_content` variable :

   ```
    const modal_content = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content");
   ```
4. Add `active` class to modal-content in `btn.click` with a delay:

   ```
    setTimeout(()=>{
       modal_content[0].classList.add("active");
    }, 500)
   ```
5. Remove `active` class when close button clicked:

   ```
    modal_content[0].classList.remove("active");
   ```

```js
const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
const modal_content = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content");

const btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
const span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function () {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(()=>{
    modal_content[0].classList.add("active");
  }, 500)
  
}

span.onclick = function () {
  modal_content[0].classList.remove("active");
  setTimeout(()=>{
      modal.style.display = "none";
  }, 500)
  
  
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (event.target === modal) {
    modal_content[0].classList.remove("active");
  setTimeout(()=>{
      modal.style.display = "none";
  }, 500)
  }
})
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  }


.modal-content.active{
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
  /* Modal Content */
  .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(60,75,100,.14);
    transform: translateY(-40px);
    opacity:0;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }

  .close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }



/* animation*/
.fade{
  animation: fadeIn .1s ease-in .5s both;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
      opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
      opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <form action="submit">
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
          <label for="email">email:</label>
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
          <label for="Telephone">Telephone</label>
          <input type="number" id="telephone" name="telephone"><br><br>
          <label for="description">Description:</label>
          <input type="text" id="description" name="description"><br><br>
          <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```